# Boto3 describe_auto_scaling_instances locks up

Tags: boto3, autoscaling

I'm trying to pull the instances from AWS AutoScaling using Boto3 (python 3). However, when executing the Boto3 methods, they just lock up without throwing any error. Anyone else run into this and figure out a workaround?

```
import boto3
autoscale = boto3.client("autoscaling")
instance_id = [[EC2 instance ID]]
asi = autoscale.describe_auto_scaling_instances(InstanceIds=[],MaxRecords=50])
print(asi)
iiag = autoscale.describe_auto_scaling_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], MaxRecords=50)
```

I've tried a number of things and it sometimes locks up at the asi declaration and sometimes at the iiag declaration.  Without Boto3 throwing an error, I'm not exactly sure why it just sits there and doesn't progress in execution.

Comment: The function can make multiple API calls to AWS to get your data. So how long it hangs for? Also do you observer same behaviour using [cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html)? In addition, you are calling this from your localhost, or some ec2 instance or lambda? All of them are slow, or only in one case?

Comment: It will hang for tens of minutes without resolution until I kill it.  I haven't used the CLI since I can get each individual row to execute just fine, but when run all the lines in unison, it dies.  This is from an EC2 instance inside the AutoScaling group.  All of them reflect this behavior.

Comment: I would check using CLI in one of these instances if possible to be sure this is an instance level issue, not specific to boto3 or your program. I also would test it form lambda or some fresh instance to know if the issue is tied to only your instances, or its a system wide problem for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have access to lambda (security restriction) and since it works when I execute individual lines, I doubt CLI will help. All of the instances I've tried this on (100 instances in our AutoScale group) exhibit this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute individual lines"?

Comment: What about about API [throttling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/throttling.html) of requests? If you have 100 instances using the API you might be getting throttled?

Comment: If I execute each line individually in the python console, each line executes just fine. It's when they are run serially in a script that they lock up. API Throttling could affect us when our 100-instance group is running - I'll have to look into that some more. However, right now, there's only one instance in the group right now.

Comment: I run your code snipped in my lambda multiple times on my asg. Haven't observed anything strange. I also run it in a loop to get more requests, and it also works till throttling limit is reached. In that case there is error: `ClientError: An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the DescribeAutoScalingInstances operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded`.

Comment: I haven't received any errors in the response, it just hangs for me.  However, I'm now exploring breaking the autoscale calls out into its own module and that is seeing some success. I wonder if it's an issue with instantiating the two boto3 clients within the same context or a gc issue...  Will continue to explore this.  I'll also be submitting a request to our admin for an increased throttle limit to avoid hitting the threshold.

Comment: It might be auto retrying and not exposing the errors?  Check cloudtrail and see if you can find the API calls showing up there (keep in mind there's up to a 15 minute lag on the event happening and it being searchable in cloudtrail

Comment: Yes, I see all of the requests in CloudTrail and they aren't showing any errors. It looks like my queries are being received, but I'm not sure what's happening from there.